# Не присваивается значение объекту html страницы по его id

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

На странице представления .cshtml пытаюсь присвоить значение объекту по его id следующим образом:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="dateRegist" type="date" asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <input value="Текущая дата регистрации" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="stateDate('dateRegist')" />
                </div>
            </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    
    <script>
        function stateDate(idObject) {
            var today = new Date();
            //var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            //var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            //var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            //today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            document.getElementById(idObject).innerHTML = today.getDate;
        }
    </script>
    
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    @{
        if (TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            <script>
            alert('@TempData["msg"]')
            </script>
        }
    }
}
```

Функция отрабатывает полностью - без ошибок, но значение объекту с id="dateRegist" не присваивается почему-то

Comment: скобочки забыли после getDate?

Comment: @КонстантинРыбаков, нет, это не повлияло

Comment: `id="dateRegist" ` у вас `input`. Для данного тега надо ставить свойство `value`, а не `innerHTML `.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, спасибо, вы правы